# Saving multiple images in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to save multiple images in an array to the database, but I'm struggling with that. I've managed to be able to upload the multiple images to the folder just not the database.

My controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $content = new Content();

    $request->validate($this->getRules());

    $content->fill($this->getSafeInput($request));

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
        {
            $destinationPath = 'content_images/';
            $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            $content->image = $filename;

        }

    }

    $content->save();

    return redirect()->route('content.index');
}
```

My form

```
<div class="content-form">
    {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'content.store', 'method' => 'post','files'=>'true' )) }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" name="title">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"></input>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

Comment: What's your desired end structure of the database to retrieve the array of images later? Maybe have all the paths of the images separated by ';' ?
As of now you're saving the name of the last image file in the database because you are saving after the foreach is done looping. 

You may also consider saving the complete path to the image instead of just the name.

Comment: I was thinking of  maybe exploding the array after ';'

Comment: youre missing this part..  enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 8):

You are overriding the value of  `$content->image` on each image save so finally your `$content->image` will have only the name of the last image.

**This should work:**

```
if($request->hasFile('image'))
{
    $names = [];
    foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
    {
        $destinationPath = 'content_images/';
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        array_push($names, $filename);          

    }
    $content->image = json_encode($names)
}
```

Here the image names are initially stored in an array and the array later is saved into db in `json` format. so that you can later access them by doing `json_decode` and you will have your array of names back!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the routes of the images separated by ';' you could do something like

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

$content = new Content();

$request->validate($this->getRules());

$content->fill($this->getSafeInput($request));

$allImages = null;

if($request->hasFile('image'))
{
    foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
    {
        $destinationPath = 'content_images/';
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $fullPath = $destinationPath . $filename;
        $allImages .= $allImages == null ? $fullPath : ';' . $fullPath;
    }

    $content->image = $allImages;

}

$content->save();

return redirect()->route('content.index');
}
```

This should make `$allImages`a string with each of the paths to the images saved and then save it all in the `Content`model.